# Fetching Data from DataBase (Access2016)

Tags: java, database, netbeans

I tried to Fetch a data from ACCESS2016 on NetBeans(8.1) i opened the control panel and choose administrative tool and DataSource(ODBC) then i selected my driver and connected the Database with project so What's The Problem ?

hint:
i'm still at the beginning on database this is my first project which i use Database on it

**Console Window**

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.database.project
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:659)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:758)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

**My Code**

```
   package java.database.project;
    import java.sql.*;
    public class JavaDatabaseProject {
        Connection con ;
        Statement st ;
        ResultSet rs ;

         public void connect() 
        {

        try{
            String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
            Class.forName(driver);
            String JavaDatabaseProject = "jdbc:odbc:DB1";

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(JavaDatabaseProject);
        st = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "select * from Tablel";
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next())
        {
            String fname = rs.getString("Fname");
            String lname = rs.getString("Lname");
            String age = rs.getString("Age");

            System.out.println(fname + " " + lname + " " + age);   

        }

        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            }

}
        public JavaDatabaseProject()
        {
            connect();
        }

public static void main(String[] args)
   {  
       new JavaDatabaseProject();
   }
}
```

Comment: how i can fix it ?

Comment: Did you see the answer in the duplicate question? Need to remove `java` from your package name.